# pdb won't stop on continue statement when nested within a conditional with multiple arguments

Tags: python-3.x, pdb

I am trying to debug a piece of code like (Python 3.6.5):

```
for i in range(10):
    if(i<100 or i < 1000):
        continue
```

If I put a break point at line 3 (i.e. `continue`), `pdb` does not stop at the `continue` statement. However, if I change the conditional to `if(i<100)`, and put the breakpoint in, `pdb` stops at the line.

My intuition says that this is the result of some on-the-fly optimization saying that not much happens here so code control never flows there.

**Question:**
How do I get `pdb` to stop at the line when there multiple elements in the conditional?